# Where do I put my concatenated file path when saving files in Python?

Tags: python, path, save

I'm trying to save an image to a specific folder, but I can't figure out where to put my path. `savename` at the end of my path is a variable.

Relevant code:

```
for vv in object_pixel_value_list:
    hollowmask = Image.eval(mask,lambda i: findpixels(i, pixval=vv))
    blackmask = Image.eval(mask,makeblack)
    complete = Image.composite(blackmask,nomask,hollowmask)
    savename = 'complete.f%03d.png' % vv
    complete.save("~/Desktop/Experiment/Neuro_images/"savename.png, "png")
```

Error received:

```
File "<ipython-input-52-f6a16ee0812c>", line 6
   complete.save("~/Desktop/Experiment/Neuro_images/"savename.png, "png")
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to expand the `~` to the users home directory. Then add the savename to the expanded path.

```
import os
filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Experiment/Neuro_images/"), savename)
complete.save(filepath, "png")
```

Don't fiddle with classic string concatenation when you're dealing with path names.

Comment: +1, and if you make a lot path / file manipulation, install the path.py lib. It makes it even easier.

Answer (score 1):

you want:

`complete.save("~/Desktop/Experiment/Neuro_images/" + savename, "png")`

Comment: @bernie, are you sure that "png" is not another argument to `complete.save()` ?

Comment: You are right, @Cameron. It is possible to specify `"png"` as a second argument. I rolled back the edit.

Comment: @bernie actually you can skip it since the filename already has the extension: [Image.save](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#Image.save) : _If format is omitted, the format is determined from the filename extension, if possible._

Answer (score 1):

`complete.save("~/Desktop/Experiment/Neuro_images/%s" % savename)`
Hope that helps...

Comment: this would give him `"~/Desktop/Experiment/Neuro_images/complete.fxxxd.png.png"`

Answer (score 1):

```
complete.save("~/Desktop/Experiment/Neuro_images/"savename.png, "png")
```

should be

```
complete.save("~/Desktop/Experiment/Neuro_images/" + savename + ".png")
```